# DateTime field and Html.TextBoxFor() helper. How to use it correctly?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html-helper

I have a DateTime field in my Model. If I try to use this field in a strong typed partial view this way

```
<%= Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.DataUdienza.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"), new { style = "width: 120px" })  %>
```

I will get the following compilation error at runtime

```
System.InvalidOperationException : Templates can be used only with field access, property access, single-dimension array index, or single-parameter custom indexer expressions.
```

Anyway if I use it removing the formatting, **ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")**, everything works but the field is formatted using the time part which I dont need at all.

Where I am doing wrong? Which is the correct way to handle this?

thanks for helping!

**EDIT**

This is the property declaration in the model class

```
[Required]
[DisplayName("Data Udienza")]
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")]
public DateTime DataUdienza { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Create an editor template called DateTime.ascx

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<System.DateTime?>" %>
<%=Html.TextBox("", (Model.HasValue ? Model.Value.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") : string.Empty), ViewData) %>
```

Put it in your Views/Shared/EditorTemplates folder.  Now when you call:

```
<%= Html.EditorFor(model => model.DataUdienza) %>
```

Your DateTime will be formatted without the time.

This will happen with all DateTimes called this way, though...

Custom html attributes can be used in this way:

```
<%= Html.EditorFor(model => model.DataUdienza, new {customAttr = "custom", @class = "class"}) %>
```

It passes through to the EditorTemplate as ViewData.

Answer (score 24):

i use this in mvc 4. it also works~

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.DatePurchase, "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", new { @class = "dateInput", @placeholder = "plz input date" })
```

Comment: Thanks very nice solution. but i really need to see why it has not used the culture info of the settings specified in the web config.

Answer (score 19):

```
<%= Html.EditorFor(model => model.DataUdienza) %>
```

And in your model:

```
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, 
               DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}")]
public DateTime DataUdienza { get; set; }
```

---

The drawback with EditorFor is that you cannot apply custom html attributes to the generated field. As an alternative you could use the `TextBox` helper:

```
<%= Html.TextBox("DataUdienza", Model.Date.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"), new { style = "width: 120px" })%>
```

Comment: Wow! Superfast. Thank you :) I'm gonna try it. But, in the meanwhile, how does this work if the field is a Nullable type?

Comment: Works the same for nullable types.

Comment: I have tried to apply your solution but unfortunately does'nt work. I am gonna edit the post to add the model property declaration for your information.

Comment: @Lorenzo, did you notice that `Html.EditorFor` should be used instead of `Html.TextBoxFor`?

Comment: @Darin: I have never used the EditorFor before. Anyway please consider that the two attributes (DataType and DisplayFormat) have been added now for trying your suggestion.

Comment: Thanks for this, I'm using the textbox helper because I needed the field to be readonly so I must pass in new {@readonly="readonly"}

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

At least if using razor, you can name the template, so you don't need to use the same template for all DateTimes:

```razor
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.StartDate, "Date")
```

where Date.cshtml contains a TextBoxFor or some other editor, like @JungleFreak had explained:

```razor
@model DateTime?

@Html.TextBox("", Model.HasValue ? Model.Value.ToShortDateString() : string.Empty, 
    new { data_datepicker = true })
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps an extension method could be created:

```
    public static MvcHtmlString DateTimeFor<TModel, TValue>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> html, Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression)
    {
        var compilationResult = expression.Compile();
        TValue dateValue = compilationResult((TModel)html.ViewDataContainer.ViewData.Model);
        var body = (MemberExpression)expression.Body;
        return html.TextBox(body.Member.Name, (Convert.ToDateTime(dateValue)).ToCustomDateFormat(), new { id = body.Member.Name, datepicker = true });
    }
```

the method ToCustomDateFormat could be an extension method for dateTime types which returns string value in desired format.

Usage:

```
@Html.DateTimeFor(x=>x.AnyDateTimeProperty)
```

Worked fine for me (for `DateTime` and `DateTime?` properties), although I am not sure if compiling the expression on run-time is a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

just add

```
@type = 'datetime-local'
```

For Example

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.DatePurchase, new { @class = "dateInput", @placeholder = "plz input date", @type = "datetime-local" })
```