# Mvc 3 DateTime Property model Default value

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have DateTime Property in my Model class ,

Then in view I am using :

```
 @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.BirthDay, new {@disabled="true" , @value="" })
```

In my View TextBox Displayed as [01/01/0001 00:00:00] , how to force it be Empty ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3734829/datetime-field-and-html-textboxfor-helper-how-to-use-it-correctly dup

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default value of a DateTime = 01/01/0001 00:00:00

This is because a DateTime is a struct and not an object. This also counts for some other C# varables like Int where the default value = 0

Other C# variables like String are nullable by default because they are an object.

To make these structs nullable you need to add a QuestionMark to the variable declaration like

```
public DateTime? BirthDay { get; set; }
```

Now your DateTime can contain null values. And the value of your textbox will contain nothing for default

---

Adding the `?` to a struct is C# sugar for `Nullable<T>` where `T` is a struct.
So `DateTime?` can be rewritten as `Nullable<DateTime>`.

Answer (score 1):

Can this work? Change in model:

```
public DateTime? BirthDay {get; set;}
```

instead of

```
public DateTime BirthDay {get; set;}
```

Comment: Try to explain why this works so this solution won't just work for this problem but he also will have the knowledge for the future

Answer (score 0):

this will do it.

```
@Html.TextBox("BirthDay", "", new {@disabled="true" })
```

It doesn't strongly type the `TextBox` so you can set any value you want, binding in the other direction will work as normal,

[Html.Textbox VS Html.TextboxFor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5908523/html-textbox-vs-html-textboxfor)